# Generate vectors using a pattern of numbers

Tags: matlab

I want to generate two vectors of equal length (n) from numbers that follow a specific pattern for each vector. For n=10 the vectors would be

```
  V1 = [2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5] and V2 = [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4]
```

For very large  n How can I automate the generation of these vectors by following the same pattern.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically looking for `row` and `column` indices of upper/lower triangular matrix. So, we can use `find` and `triu` -

```
[v2,v1] = find(triu(true(5),1))
```

Sample run -

```
>> [v2,v1] = find(triu(true(5),1));
>> v1.'
ans =
     2     3     3     4     4     4     5     5     5     5
>> v2.'
ans =
     1     1     2     1     2     3     1     2     3     4
```

We can also [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create the upper triangular matrix, like so -

```
bsxfun(@lt,(1:5)',1:5)
```